# want to know the difference between in_time column from one table to in_time column from another table

Tags: mysql, time

i have table name as time_tracking in which i have column as id which is primary key and in_time,out_time.also i have another table as fixed_shift in there having column as in_time(primary key) and out_time(unique key).
i have values in fixed_shift table

```
# in_time, out_time
09:00:00, 18:00:00
18:00:00, 21:00:00
```

and values in time_tracking table is

```
id, in_time,       out_time, count
2,  09:30:00.0000, 17:45:00.0000 
3,  09:45:00.0000, 18:00:00.0000
```

now i want the result which shows id='3' got late by 45 minutes.and this we will get to know by minus the in_time from time_tracking table and fixed_shift table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TIMEDIFF` function. Something like below.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(b.in_time, a.in_time), a.id
FROM fixed_shift a, time_tracking b
WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: As showning in question table fixed_shift doesn't have id column

Comment: Oh Okay. So he want to have check on all rows with all fixed time rows?. This can be done by removing the where condition and will result in an cartesian product or cross join.